# Java Project from Existing Ant Buildfile errors

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I am new at Ant Buildfile and I have a specific problem. I am trying to make a new Java Project from Existing Ant Buildfile and when I add my Ant Buildfile archive , build.xml , and create the project I am getting bunch of errors.

The .xml archive is given to me. I have tried a lot of things yet nothing works. I would like some help because that's for a semester exam and **the teacher doesnt give any help**.

[image: Error messages]

There is no point sending the .xml archive because I don't think that's wrong from the moment the teacher gave it to us.

Thanks in regard!

Comment: Hi & Welcome! Your errors implies missing libraries (in your eclipse project) ... (but since teacher is teacher, and this probably "works"), you can try : 1. to invoke `ant` from command line (to see how that works out([manual](https://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html)) ..since "everything is old", you might need an earlier version of ant/java(!)) 2. (indep. from 1.) .. to manually "resolve the libs" (they should be somewhere "close"/in "lib" folder, at least referenced in the build.xml)

Comment: Looks like a project for Java 8 or lower, but you have a higher Java version. Use Java 8 or avoid dependencies containing packages that also exist in the system library (because this is not allowed since Java 9). Telling _"the teacher doesnt give any help"_ does not help.